# enable session in custom role and membership providers

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, web-config

I have custom role and membership providers. I want use this [Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607392/Custom-Role-Providers) in asp.net 4 no mvc.

and use this code in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

custom membership providers and project it's worked but session is not worked in project.

I use this code for Login:

```
private User SetupFormsAuthTicket(string userName, bool persistanceFlag)
    {
        User user;
        UsersContext usersContext = new UsersContext();
            user = usersContext.GetUser(userName);

        var userId = user.UserId;
        var userData = userId.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, //version
                            userName, // user name
                            DateTime.Now,             //creation
                            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), //Expiration
                            persistanceFlag, //Persistent
                            userData);

        var encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
        return user;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you have this in your *web.config*?

```
<sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect" regenerateExpiredSessionId="true" timeout="20" />
```

Comment: I use your code and cookieless="UseCookies" but is not worked.

Comment: yes. but its not working. Is my code for custom role and membership providers the correct?: <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>